# Linking Metabase to Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, metabase

My company is heavily using Metabase data and there is a specific query that I would like to link to Google Sheets. How I'd like it to work would be that instead of me downloading a CSV file and updating the data in the sheet manually, it should be linked to Metabase and entries can be addeded to the sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if download link is not private you could do:

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://download-link.csv")
```

or query it directly:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://download-link.csv"), "select Col1,Col2", 0)
```

Comment: thank you @player0, with this, will it autoupdate a single entry added on metabase?

Comment: @VinceTan yes, it should

Comment: Assuming your Metabase instance is publicly accessible and sharing is enabled, you should be able to get the link to download the CSV from the shared view of the question

Answer (score 0):

In addition to player0 response, you should enable "Recalculation" => On Change and Every Minute in the sheet settings
[image]